# How to stream information using websockets in python?

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio

I am teaching myself websockets and wrote this code

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def stream_msgs(uri,msg):
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg)
        rec= await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {rec}")



asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete( stream_msgs('wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv',"{op:unconfirmed_sub}"))
```

The problem is it exits the program after receiving a message. When I did  a test with [this tool](http://websocket.org/echo.html) the same was streaming informations. How can I stream data using websockets in python?

Comment: Have you wrapping the send/recv/print block in a `while True` loop - e.g. `async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket: while True: ...`?

Comment: Can I ask a question. Web-sockets work as a full duplex system. Isn't  sending a message is enough to get the stream instead of wrapping it in while loop?